# Is it possible to retrieve a raw query from Oracle OCI library?

Tags: c++, sql, database, oracle10g, informix

I am looking to retrieve the raw query bytes from an Oracle statement and copy them directly into a POD C structure. The reason for this is due to legacy code that must be ported to using Oracle from Informix. I'll illustrate what I basically need below. I have been looking into using the Oracle Template Library (OTL) but I have been unable to thus far find a way to retrieve the underlying byte data directly from the stream.

The problem is that I want to issue several SELECT queries, with varying column outputs, from the same function call (this is the current mode of operation for Informix).

```
int query( char* inputQueryBuf, char* outputQueryBuf);
```

Comment: I'm curious how the Informix stuff works.  None of the documented interfaces provides access to the raw tuple buffer - AFAIK.

Comment: I would love to share, but most of that fun stuff is under special license terms.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to unburry this old thread, but why can use the oracle `v$sql` to retrieve recently running queries?

```
SELECT *
FROM gv$sql;
```